# Bootstrap 5 Drop Menu expansion changes div size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have a bootstrap 5 menu in development.

On mobile devices, when clicking the toggler, the parent div, which contains a background image, temporarily expands to the height of the toggler drop menu (see 2nd image below).  Everything then adjusts properly and the drop menu overlays the parent div (and the background image) correctly (see 1st image below).

I'm trying to stop the menu from resizing it's parent div when clicked.

See my attachments for screenshots of how the menu influences it's parent div height.

```css
#wordpress-page-header {
  background-image: url('images/wordpress-backgrounds/wordpress_home-header-background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar-nav {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-dark {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0.4rem;
  padding-left: 0.4rem;
}

.nav-item {
  background-color: #636363;
  border-bottom: #ababab;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  margin: 20px;
}

.nav-item-last {
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row" id="wordpress-page-header" style="">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" width="637" height="278" alt="Wordpress Developer Logo - Get Wordpress Help" class="img-fluid" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-6">
    <nav class="navbar ms-auto sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark" aria-label="main nav bar">

      <!-- note this has to stay for proper alignment of the toggler -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-nav-bar" aria-controls="main-nav-bar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-bar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') !== false):?>active<?php endif; ?>" href="../index.php">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'about') !== false):?>active<?php endif; ?>" href="../about.php">About</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'services') !== false):?>active<?php endif; ?>" href="../wordpress-services.php">Services</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'kudos') !== false):?>active<?php endif; ?>" href="../wordpress-kudos.php">Kudos</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'clients') !== false):?>active<?php endif; ?>" href="../wordpress-clients.php">Clients</a></li>

          <li class="nav-item nav-item-last"><a class="nav-link <?php if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'contact') !== false):?>active<?php endif; ?>" href="../contact-wordpress-support.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <!-- empty div-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 orange-box d-none d-lg-block">
        <a href="/contact-wordpress-support.php">EMAIL US</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="">
      <div class="col-6" style="">
        <!-- empty div-->
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 orange-box orange-box-call-us d-none d-lg-block">
        CALL US<br>
        <span id="header-phone-number" class="text-white text-decoration-none">
          <a href="tel:619272078">619-272-078</a>
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The first pic shows how i want the menu and it's parent div to appear at all times.

The second pic shows how the menu temporarily makes it's parent div taller. I don't want this to happen.

[image: Menu correct]

[image: Menu expands parent div. I don't want this.]

Comment: All information must be in your post, not down here in comments.

Comment: I've converted your code to a demo snippet. Please edit your post, then revise the snippet to show the problem.